# JavaFX TableView with complex TableColumn

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

Similar to the question here: [Javafx tableview with data from multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571776/javafx-tableview-with-data-from-multiple-classes)
I am trying to create a table composed of more than one class.  The backend is sqlite tables and I am trying to implement the Toxi solution found here: http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas  That is why my simplified example below is the way it is - split up into unnecessary classes.

It is the Tag column I am trying to figure out.  Is a wrapper class the cleanest way to go,a BookmarkTag class?  Can you setup event handlers to fill out this other column when the row is updated?  Ultimately the cell will contain a fancier display of the tags (clickable icons).

Thank you.

My main class:

```
package complextableview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComplexTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ObservableList<Bookmark> bookmarks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Tag> tags = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<TagMap> tagMapList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        TableView<Bookmark> bookmarkTV = new TableView<>(bookmarks);        
        TableColumn<Bookmark, String> bookmarkNameCol = new TableColumn<>("URL");        
        // What to put here?
        //TableColumn<?, String> bookmarkTagCol = new TableColumn<>("Tags");

        bookmarkNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));        
        // What to put here?
        //bookmarkTagCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("?"));

        bookmarkTV.getColumns().add(bookmarkNameCol);
        //bookmarkTV.getColumns().add(bookmarkTagCol);

        // Populate data
        bookmarks.add(new Bookmark(0, "stackoverflow.com"));
        bookmarks.add(new Bookmark(1, "reddit.com"));

        tags.add(new Tag(0, "work"));
        tags.add(new Tag(1, "home"));
        tags.add(new Tag(2, "fun"));

        tagMapList.add(new TagMap(0, 0, 0)); // 1st mapping = google & "work"
        tagMapList.add(new TagMap(1, 1, 1)); // 2nd mapping = reddit & "home"
        tagMapList.add(new TagMap(2, 1, 2)); // 3rd mapping = reddit & "fun"

        // Table Output
        // URL                Tags
        // stackoverflow.com  'work'
        // reddit.com         'home,fun'

        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for ( TagMap tagMapping : tagMapList ){
            if ( tagMapping.getBookmarkId() == 1)
                sb1.append(tags.get(tagMapping.getTagId()).getString());            
            else
                sb2.append(tags.get(tagMapping.getTagId()).getString());            
        }

        System.out.println(sb1.toString());
        System.out.println(sb2.toString());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(bookmarkTV);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("ComplexTableView");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And the other classes:

Bookmark

```
package complextableview;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Bookmark {
    private final StringProperty name;
    private final IntegerProperty id;

    public Bookmark() {
        id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id", 0);
        name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", "");
    }

    public Bookmark(Integer id, String name) {
        this();
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
    }

    public final Integer getId() {return id.get();}
    public final void setId(Integer value) {id.set(value);}
    public IntegerProperty getIdProperty() {return id;}
    public final String getName() {return name.get();}
    public final void setName(String value) {name.set(value);}
    public StringProperty getNameProperty() {return name;}
}
```

Tag

```
package complextableview;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Tag {

    public final StringProperty string;
    public final IntegerProperty id;

    public Tag() {
        id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id", 0);
        string = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "string", "");
    }
    public Tag(Integer id, String string) {
        this();
        setId(id);
        setString(string);
    }

    public final Integer getId() {return id.get();}
    public final void setId(Integer value) {id.set(value);}
    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {return id;}
    public final String getString() {return string.get();}
    public final void setString(String value) {string.set(value);}
    public StringProperty stringProperty() {return string;}
}
```

TagMap

```
package complextableview;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class TagMap {

    public final IntegerProperty id;
    public final IntegerProperty bookmarkId;
    public final IntegerProperty tagId;

    public TagMap(){
        id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id", 0);
        bookmarkId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "bookmarkId", 0);
        tagId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "tagId", 0);
    }

    public TagMap(Integer id, Integer bmId, Integer tagId) {
        this();

        setId(id);
        setBookmarkId(bmId);
        setTagId(tagId);
    }

    public final Integer getId() {return id.get();}
    public final void setId(Integer value) {id.set(value);}
    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {return id;}
    public final Integer getTagId() {return tagId.get();}
    public final void setTagId(Integer value) {tagId.set(value);}
    public IntegerProperty tagIdProperty() {return tagId;}
    public final Integer getBookmarkId() {return bookmarkId.get();}
    public final void setBookmarkId(Integer value) {bookmarkId.set(value);}
    public IntegerProperty bookmarkIdProperty() {return bookmarkId;}
}
```

Comment: What do you want the table to look like? What goes in the tag column, and what is in each row? I.e. do you want one row for each bookmark, or are you going to have multiple rows for bookmarks that have multiple tags?

Comment: So can you arrange for your `Bookmark` class to have a list of tags as one of its properties. That would be the usual JPA representation of the data in the database.

Comment: The table would have one row per bookmark and multiple tags in the tag column, so:  
URL                            Tag  
-----------------------------------  
stackoverflow.com     'work, informative'  
reddit.com                  'home, fun, informative'  

I just found your response to another question that may be similar
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571747/tableview-with-different-objects-javafx  
and am trying to read through it now. :)

Comment: I was keeping the class as close to the sqlite table as possible.  I guess I should have another wrapper class around it?

Comment: Typically you represent the data on the OO side without a class representation of the join table. This looks like a one-many relationship: see how [JPA manages it](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)

Comment: James, I appreciate the feedback, that wiki page is a nice resource!  I'm a novice with databases as well so I may not have it right.  My example doesn't show it but I would think that if one website could have multiple tags: "work, programming" and one tag ('programming') could be used for multiple sites (stackoverflow.com, java.com), then it would be many to many?

Comment: Yes, that's true... You would still not typically model the join table. The advantage from this perspective of doing it this way is that is would then fit very well into the tableview