# TableView for different objects throughout the application

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

Is it possible to have a TableView that is able to maintain different kinds of objects during runtime, but only objects of one kind at a time?

The specific case I am facing is a TableView that I want to use to display results of searches. These searches may produce different "objects" as outcomes, let's say the obligatory `Person` and `Address`. When the user searches for either, the outcome would be a set of either `Person` or `Address`.
After a search the table would be accordingly changed (`getItems().clear();` and `getColumns().clear();`) however I am already stuck at implementing the filling.
I got the TableView declared as `TableView<?> searchResults` that is initialized with FXML. Now I tried to add a `new TableColumn<Person, String>` to the table and faced an error:

```
'add(javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<capture<?>,?>)' in 'java.util.List' cannot be applied to '(javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<de.wolfsburg.stadt.beurteilungFX.controllers.tabletypes.CheckNote,java.lang.String>)'
```

So this does not appear to be working clearly.
As the classes I got are both implementing the same Interface I also tried declaring the TableView as `TableView<? extends MyInterface>` and `TableView<MyInterface>` with no success in either case.
Eventhough they implement the same Interface the classes differ in number of fields and name of fields.

So the question again: Can one have a TableView that supports multiple objects of the same class and multiple classes?

Note: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23571747/6707985) during research but seems to be a question asking about different classes at the same time whereas mine asks for objects of the same class at first and change of class later.

Sure an alternative would be having two `TableView`s at the same time and hiding one or the other. But this would consume a lot of memory in bigger usecases where 10+ different classes might need to be supported.

Comment: Using `TableView<MyInterface>` should work, but why not just replace the table?

Comment: `TableView<MyInterface>` still does not accept any `TableColumn<ImplementingClass, String>`. What is the idea with replacing the table? The one I mentioned in the end? Because I wanted to get around something like this and as the application will be upgraded/expanded I do not want to face the problem described. If replacing meant to create a new TableView this does not work either as the declared type stays the same and will still not accept the above mentioned columns. I added a note that the Interface is not responsible for number of fields and naming of them.

Comment: If you have a `TableView<MyInterface>` then you need to use `TableColumn<MyInterface, String>` (or other column types). By replacing the table, I meant (for example) remove the `TableView<Person>` entirely from the UI, and add a new `TableView<Address>` when you want to display it. There is no need to keep a table in memory that you are not showing.

Comment: And the former would not enable me to access any fields of the subclasses using a `PropertyValueFactory`, correct? So either I would write my own callback for each column that will typecast to the corresponding class or I will have to go for the latter...

Comment: A `PropertyValueFactory` uses reflection, so there is no compile-time type checking, and you should be able to use whatever properties you want. But I would prefer the latter solution anyway.

Comment: Still I would have to use the Classname to have the reflection know where to look for, or am I wrong? And this will then prevent me from adding the Factory as the CellValueFactory of the column. I will see where I will go with this knowledge :) If you could post an answer so that this is "officially" closed and I can (barely) thank you for your time and effort, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using the interface, as shown below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewViaInterface extends Application {

    private TableView<TableEntry> table ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        table = new TableView<>();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        Button showPersonTable = new Button("Person table");
        showPersonTable.setOnAction(e -> showPersonTable());
        Button showAddressTable = new Button("Address table");
        showAddressTable.setOnAction(e -> showAddressTable());

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, showPersonTable, showAddressTable);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setBottom(buttons);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showPersonTable() {
        table.getColumns().clear();
        TableColumn<TableEntry, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        table.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);

        TableColumn<TableEntry, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);

        // populate table...
    }

    private void showAddressTable() {
        table.getColumns().clear();
        TableColumn<TableEntry, String> streetCol = new TableColumn<>("Street");
        streetCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("street"));
        table.getColumns().add(streetCol);

        TableColumn<TableEntry, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>("City");
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("city"));
        table.getColumns().add(cityCol);

        // populate table...

    }

    public interface TableEntry {}
    public class Person implements TableEntry {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

    }

    public class Address implements TableEntry {
        private final StringProperty street = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();
        public final StringProperty streetProperty() {
            return this.street;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getStreet() {
            return this.streetProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setStreet(final java.lang.String street) {
            this.streetProperty().set(street);
        }

        public final StringProperty cityProperty() {
            return this.city;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getCity() {
            return this.cityProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setCity(final java.lang.String city) {
            this.cityProperty().set(city);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Though I would recommend replacing the table entirely when you want to switch tables:

```
public class TableViewViaInterface extends Application {

    private BorderPane root ;
    private TableView<? extends TableEntry> table ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new BorderPane();
        Button showPersonTable = new Button("Person table");
        showPersonTable.setOnAction(e -> showPersonTable());
        Button showAddressTable = new Button("Address table");
        showAddressTable.setOnAction(e -> showAddressTable());

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5, showPersonTable, showAddressTable);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setBottom(buttons);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showPersonTable() {

        TableView<Person> personTable = new TableView<>();
        personTable.getColumns().clear();
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        personTable.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        personTable.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);

        // populate table...

        this.table = personTable ;
        root.setCenter(personTable);
    }

    private void showAddressTable() {

        TableView<Address> addressTable = new TableView<>();
        addressTable.getColumns().clear();
        TableColumn<Address, String> streetCol = new TableColumn<>("Street");
        streetCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().streetProperty());
        addressTable.getColumns().add(streetCol);

        TableColumn<Address, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>("City");
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().cityProperty());
        addressTable.getColumns().add(cityCol);

        // populate table...

        this.table = addressTable ;
        root.setCenter(addressTable);

    }

    // interface and classes as above...
}
```

Note that when you switch tables, the previous table and all its data become eligible for garbage collection, as there are no references to the old table retained.

Comment: This clearly does work! I was concerned at first as I looked into the implementation of how the value is got within the PropertyValueFactory and only saw the method referencing the `S` part of the corresponding `CellDataFeatures<S, T>` which in my case would be `MyInterface` and that clearly does not have the fields I thought the method was looking for. But I guess I just misunderstood something there.
Thanks for your time, effort and help!

Comment: @geisterfurz007 As I mentioned in the comments below your question, the `PropertyValueFactory` uses reflection, so it only relies on the runtime type of the objects in each row, not on the compile-time type of the table. I added a version showing how I would do it.